Trying to pass a value from a global function
I'm trying to pass a Double value from a function called from another view and the function returns a value before the AlamoFire request completes
struct GetPrice {

    static func getThePrice(book: String) async -> Double? {
        
        var theNetPrice: Double = 0.0
        var iListPrice = ""
        let url = "https://example.com"
        
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "accept": "application/xml",
            "Authorization": "Basic \xxx",
           
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]

        let body: [String: Any] = ["xxxxx"]

        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseData { response in
            var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
                //print("response.result ", response.result)
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let data = response.data
                let s = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                let xml = XMLHash.parse(String(s!))
                
                    iListPrice = xml["xxx"].element!.text
                    theNetPrice = Double(iListPrice)
                    print(theNetPrice) // this shows correct value
                    //return theNetPrice -- this would give error 'Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to closure result type 'Void''
            case .failure(let error):
                statusCode = error._code
                print("status code is: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
                
                print(error)
            }
        }
        
        return theNetPrice //returns 0.0
    }
}
'''


I don't know the XML library you are using, but does this
xml["xxx"].element!.text return a String or a Double as required for theNetPrice?

@workingdogsupportUkraine I left some code out that wasn't relevant so the questions wasn't too long.   I edited the code above so it answers your question.  theNetPrice gets the correct Double value in the case .success block but only after the function returns the default value of 0.0

Your AF.request is asynchronous, that means your return theNetPrice //returns 0.0
is done before your request has finished. Try moving that in the case .failure part.

@workingdogsupportUkraine thanks I did know that was the issue.  I don’t know how to solve it and get the function to return the Double value from the AF.request

Try this approach using a continuation as shown in the example code.
struct GetPrice {

    static func getThePrice(book: String) async -> Double? {
        //..
        return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
                .responseData { response in
                    var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
                    //print("response.result ", response.result)
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        let data = response.data
                        let s = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                        let xml = XMLHash.parse(String(s!))
                        
                        iListPrice = xml["xxx"].element!.text
                        theNetPrice = Double(iListPrice)
                        print(theNetPrice) // this shows correct value

                        continuation.resume(returning: theNetPrice)

                    case .failure(let error):
                        statusCode = error._code
                        print("status code is: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
                        print(error)

                        continuation.resume(returning: theNetPrice)

                    }
                }
        }

    }
}

Use it with something like
 Task {
     let price = await GetPrice.getThePrice(book: "MyBook")
     if let price = price {
         print("The price is: \(price)")
     }
 }

Or you could try using a completion handler, such as
 static func getThePrice(book: String, completion: @escaping (Double?) -> Void) {
     //..
         AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
             .responseData { response in
                 var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
                 //print("response.result ", response.result)
                 switch response.result {
                 case .success:
                     let data = response.data
                     let s = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                     let xml = XMLHash.parse(String(s!))
                     
                     iListPrice = xml["xxx"].element!.text
                     theNetPrice = Double(iListPrice)
                     print(theNetPrice) // this shows correct value
                     
                    completion(theNetPrice)
 
                 case .failure(let error):
                     statusCode = error._code
                     print("status code is: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
                     print(error)
 
                    completion(theNetPrice)

                 }
             }
     }

Use it like this:
 GetPrice.getThePrice(book: "MyBook") { price in
         if let price = price {
             print("The price is: \(price)")
         }
     }


Thank you!  Continuation worked @workingdogukraine
